# show div inside current slide slick

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

i'm using slider slick and i'm trying to display some div with quote only on current slide. I tried to do it in that way:

```
function displayQuote() {
 if ($('div').hasClass("slick-current")) {
  $(this).find('.quote').css('display', 'block');
 }
}
displayQuote();
```

but it doesn't work. here is full code: 
http://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/JYyjew

I'm just beginner so I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simpler than that. First you need to hide all captions. Once the captions are hidden you need to show the caption of the current slide. When a slide becomes active (current slide), it slick gives it a class slick-active. You use that and display the caption inside that class. Following is the code for it. I hope this solves your problem.

```
figcaption {
   display: none;
}

.slick-active figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```